# VBA Macro Match Data Return Value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying but kept failing. If any could help, would much appreciated!

I want to write a macro to compare data Column A with Column B
If Column is Blank, I want to fill the data like "Need to provide Name"
Then loop through entire column rows and fill the match data but not have names in column C.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I think I can solve your problem, but I'd need clearer explanation. By "If Column is Blank" you mean blank cells? And what is supposed to happen with column C again?

Comment: Sorry for the confusions. I want to look up data in column A if it is match with Column B, if it does, then if cell in column C is blank, give a value, else if the cell in column C is not blank, skip it.

Comment: Please do not remove necessary info from your question (even after it has been answered). Questions on StackOverflow are supposed to stay ansserable, in order to make Q/A pairs which remain helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something basic for you to do that. Paste this into your sheet module and change the fields I specified on the lines to what you need it to be.

```
Sub MatchData()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long, i As Long, arr

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Set your sheet name here
lrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
arr = ws.Range("A1:C" & lrow).Value 'Change columns/starting row if needed

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 2) Then
        If arr(i, 3) = "" Then
            arr(i, 3) = "Need to provide Name" 'Put the text you want.
        End If
    End If
Next i

ws.Range("A1:C" & lrow).Value = arr 'Change columns/starting row if needed

End Sub
```

Comment: No worries. If your question is solved please mark the tick next to the answer so everyone knows it has been successfully answered.

Comment: @Simon Please double check that the question is still answerable after OPs last edit. I think relevant info was removed. If you think that you would not have been able to answer the question satisfyingly without that removed info please educate OP to keep questions answerable even after they were answered. Many new users misunderstand the purpose of StackOverflow and unintentionally make their questions unanswerable after getting the help they hoped for. Strictly speaking such questions would have to be closed and deleted - if not edited to undo the harmful edit....